# Cannot load unregistered resource /.extlib/dijit/Dialog.js

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

Domino Server running 853FP4 on Windows

Same application running on two servers behaves differently. When trying to launch an xe:dialog from a partial refresh via a button I get a message in an alert box:

An error occurred while updating some of the page. Could not load 'extlib.dijit.dialog';last tried '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.exlib/dijit/Dialog,js'

On the server that works the dialog is displayed.

If I request http:///xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/Dialog.js on the working server I get javascript source returned.

On the server that isn't working I get:

Cannot load unregistered resource /.extlib/dijit/Dialog.js

All seems to suggest extlib hasn't been loaded properly. I recreated the updatesite just in case and that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they replicas of each other, or different databases based on the same design?

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you point out is related to extlib so I would check this.

Do you see the osgi plugins being loaded if you restart the http on both servers?

Also to you got the notes.ini entry for the updatesite on both servers?

Also try a blank xpage and drag an extlib component into this one and try to load it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved. Thanks Fredrik for the suggestions (I tried those before asking the question :-) I'll explain a bit more next time a question but thank you anyway).

The think that appeared to make the difference was recreating the xsp.properties file.